# Why does mutating an object in one ArrayList change it in all other ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, scheduling, round-robin

I am making a cpu scheduling simulator (for a school project). I have a problem with my `roundRobin` function. When I do `c.get(i).jobTime -= 2;` and `c.get(i).jobTime -= 1;` it effects my other `ArrayList`s, so I can't do my other functions. Before I call `roundRobin2` my lists are completely normal. Why does this happen?

For example this is how my `list4` looks like after `roundRobin2`

`list 4: [Job101 0, Job102 0, Job103 0, Job104 0, Job105 0, Job106 0]`

This is how I read in the file, and put the `Jobs` objects into my `ArrayList`s.

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("testdata1.txt"));
ArrayList<Jobs> list = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
ArrayList<Jobs> list2 = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
ArrayList<Jobs> list3 = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
ArrayList<Jobs> list4 = new ArrayList<Jobs>();

Jobs first;

while (input.hasNext()) {
    first = new Jobs(input.next(), input.nextInt());
    list.add(first);
    list2.add(first);
    list3.add(first);
    list4.add(first);
}

input.close();
```

This is my `roundRobin2`

```java
public void roundRobin2(ArrayList<Jobs> c, int sT) {
    int size = c.size();
    int cT = 0;
    int ccT = 0;
    while (!c.isEmpty()) {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(c);
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if ((c.get(i).jobTime) >= 2) {
                c.get(i).jobTime -= 2;
                cT += 2;

                if ((c.get(i).jobTime) == 0) {
                    ccT += cT;
                }
            } else {
                (c.get(i).jobTime) -= 1;
                cT += 1;

                if ((c.get(i).jobTime) == 0) {
                    ccT += cT;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if ((c.get(i).jobTime) == 0) {
                c.remove(i);
                size = c.size();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nAverage completion times: "+ccT+"/"+sT+" = "+((ccT)/sT));
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In each iteration you are creating only a single object and adding it to all 4 lists. When you mutate that object you, well, mutate it. That mutation will be reflected in all the lists because they all store the same object reference.

```java
while (input.hasNext()) {
    first = new Jobs(input.next(), input.nextInt());
    list.add(first);
    list2.add(first);
    list3.add(first);
    list4.add(first);
}
```

Instead you need to add a new object reference to each list (if you want a clone of the object to be stored in each list).

```java
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String s = input.next();
    int i = input.nextInt();
    list.add(new Jobs(s, i));
    list2.add(new Jobs(s, i));
    list3.add(new Jobs(s, i));
    list4.add(new Jobs(s, i));
}
```

In the first code sample `list.get(n) == list2.get(n)` will be `true` (true for any valid `n` and for any two lists from your 4). In the second sample it will be `false` as you now have completely unrelated objects that just happen to store the same values at the point they are added to the list.

Comment: Thank you @AndyBrown, when I read your comment I knew did exactly what you just added. I cant believe I didnt think of that before